# Data Loader stuck at Initializing Salesforce Object and CSV file screen

Tags: data-loader, data

My data loader is stuck on the screen where the header says 'Data Selection' and the body says Initializing Salesforce object and CSV file. I have no idea what it is. I thought its because my data loader is old but i just downloaded the latest one off the salesforce site and its still causing the same issue. What could be the problem? I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: how many data you are trying to delete? maybe you should consider other means like jitterbit or dataloader.io

Comment: not much just a few hundered. i have used dataloader for more data than this. Not sure what the issue is still.

Comment: do you have some pending deployment or some other administrative task running on like batch job or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your error, please check the below article.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206248&type=1

I would suggest trying with Dataloader.io http://dataloader.io/ , it is more reliable than dataloader.

Also try, Opening the file in excel, save as new CSV file.( It worked for me for a similar issue)

Answer (score 0):

I was using a file exported from a report, which includes the footer information outlining who/when the data was extracted from Salesforce.

Editing these lines out of the csv seemed to resolve it for me.